# Agora Live Streaming: Subscribe to existing user in a chanel?

Tags: subscribe, agora-web-sdk-ng

I would like to subscribe to the existing user in a channel.
If a user(host) was published before the audience joined and subscribe host. The remote tracks do not play.
client.getClient().on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {

Comment: We need to seem the smallest code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. If you are in this post, you can try this code below:
We can use client.remoteUsers to get the remote users.
The sample code as below:

```
if (client.remoteUsers.length > 0) {
  const host = client.remoteUsers[0];
  setState((s) => {
    return {
      ...s,
      statusLive: StatusLive.live,
      isPlayed: true,
    };
  });
  if (host.hasVideo) {
    await client.subscribe(host, "video");
    host.videoTrack?.play(ref.current as HTMLElement);
  }
  if (host.hasAudio) {
    await client.subscribe(host, "audio");
    host.audioTrack?.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).